# Зуммирование сайта

Tags: php, html, css

Всем доброго дня. есть небольшой вопрос. Есть текст "Информация о доставке" При зуммировании сайта в любом из браузеров этот текст начинает выглядеть не в одну строчку а в 2 или того хуже переносится из-за чего начинает криво отображаться код. Возможно ли с помощью каких либо инструментов PHP HTML или CSS сделать так чтобы при зуме страницы текст заменялся другим либо просто то что не влезает сокращалось до троеточия...
Вот как всё на деле происходит.

Нормально:

[image: img1]

Небольшой Zoom:

[image: img2]

Большой Zoom:

[image: img3]

Вот как это прописано в коде:

```
<center style="margin-top: 7px;">
    <div class="head_cont"><img src="/image/data/forWelcome/phone.png" alt="Телефон для связи с нами"><span style="padding: 0 10px 0 5px; vertical-align: 10px;"> <span style="color: red;"></span></span></div>

    <div class="head_cont"><a href="mailto:info@test.ru" target="_blank" title="Написать нам"><img src="/image/data/forWelcome/mail.png" alt="Отправить письмо"><span style="color: #222222; padding: 0 10px 0 5px; vertical-align: 10px;">info@test.ru</span></a></div>

    <div class="head_cont_delivery"><a href="http://test.ru/delivery" title="Информация о доставке"><img src="/image/data/forWelcome/dostavka.png" alt="Доставка"><span style="color: #222222; padding: 0 10px 0 5px; vertical-align: 10px;">Информация о доставке</span></a></div>
```

И в файле стилей:

```
.head_cont {
font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
text-transform: none;
display: inline;
}

.head_cont_delivery {
font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
text-transform: none;
display: inline;
width: 100px;
height: 40px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это нормальное поведение zoom'a, он немного для другого был придуман. Я бы вам посоветовал использовать [media queries](http://habrahabr.ru/post/119127/), дабы адаптировать сайт под разные разрешения.

Comment: Мой шаблон адаптирован под media queries. Но данный модуль я писал сам, поскольку в шаблоне изначально не было такого предусмотрено. Вот поэтому то так и получается. Мб есть еще какие то варианты?

Comment: Тогда допишите стили для разных размеров для конкретно этих блоков. Например, уменьшайте отступы, меняйте расположение и в крайнем случае что-то скрывайте.